# Change Permissions for a Specific User

Tags: linux, chmod

Im new here. I have a question about changing permissions of a file. We have user1 user2 user3 and we have a "xx" file. xx files remoting by root and group1. ı have to give a writable and readable privilege for a user1(non member of group1). How can I do that?

Comment: You can do this with acls; a pointer to a tutorial would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with ACLs(Access control lists).
This is a great article you want to have a look at;
[ACL tutorial](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html#intro)

Comment: Cross linking to answers elsewhere instead of giving an answer on the site is discouraged on stackexchange (reason being those other sites could go down rendering the answer useless at a later point). Maybe you'll want to revise your answer (and refer to that link as your source, while writing what it teaches on this topic yourself)